# How to call xpath document() with resolvable base references

Tags: java, xml, xslt, xalan

I have an xml file which contains the name of another xml file:

within my stylesheet, I detect @href and open the document via the document() function

document(@href)

**should** call my URIResolver.resolve(fname,base) with base of the "Base URI of the node from which the the string of the first argument is calculated"

document(@href,.)

**should** call my URIResolver.resolve(fname,base) with base of the "Base URI of the current node"

However in practice with Xalan/J

document(@href)

is blank

and

document(@href,.)

is giving current directory of my application

How do I set base so that my URIResolver can find the file?

Comment: This is an xslt processor - dependent question (Xalan J), therefore must be tagged xsltprocessor.

Comment: Also, this question hasn't anything to do with XPath, because the `document()` function isn't an XPath function.

Comment: @Dimitre: I don't know... I think there is some misunderstood in how XSLT `document()` function works. I'm not sure this is a Xalan bug, besides what OP've written.

Comment: @Alejandro: Any question talking about URIResolver falls into the implementation-dependent group and in our case this is matched by the "xsltprocessor" tag.

Answer (score 1):

Do note that this

```
document(@href)
```

It's equal to this

```
document(string(@href),@href)
```

and so maybe also to

```
document(string(@href),.)
```

From http://www.w3.org/TR/xslt#document:

> When the document function has exactly
>   one argument and the argument is a
>   node-set, then the result is the
>   union, for each node in the argument
>   node-set, of the result of calling the
>   document function with the first
>   argument being the string-value of the
>   node, and the second argument being a
>   node-set with the node as its only
>   member.

And then

> The base URI (see [3.2 Base URI]) of
>   the node in the second argument
>   node-set that is first in document
>   order is used as the base URI for
>   resolving the relative URI into an
>   absolute URI

But this:

```
document(string(@href))
```

Will use the stylesheet URI as resolver. Because:

> When the first argument to the
>   document function is not a node-set,
>   the first argument is converted to a
>   string as if by a call to the string
>   function. This string is treated as a
>   URI reference.

And then

> If the second argument is omitted,
>   then it defaults to the node in the
>   stylesheet that contains the
>   expression that includes the call to
>   the document function.

About the question

> How do I set base so that my
>   URIResolver can find the file?

**Answer:** use the second form and [@xml:base](http://www.w3.org/TR/xmlbase/)